# How do I pull text from google document to display on my site?

Tags: google-docs-api

I have a user who wants to update the text on their website using a google document. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't looked into whether it's possible with an API, but I *do* know that it's possible to load the page and parse the contents quite easily.

Here is a (rather pointless) snippet from when I parsed a Google document using C# -

```
contents = title = browser.ResponseData;
contents = contents.Substring(contents.IndexOf(">DOCS_mutations") + 20);
contents = contents.Substring(0, contents.IndexOf("\"}") + 1);
contents = contents.Substring(contents.IndexOf("\"s\":"));
contents = contents.Substring(contents.IndexOf(":") + 1);
contents = contents.Substring(1, contents.Length - 2);

title = title.Substring(title.IndexOf("/><script type=\"text/javascript\">"));

title = title.Substring(title.IndexOf("config, '") + 9);
title = title.Substring(0, title.IndexOf("'"));
```

The above snippet is grabbing the content of the document from the HTML by parsing the following region (where *foo* was the contents of my document) -

```
DOCS_mutations = [{"ty":"is","ibi":1,"s":"foo"},
```

This information is a mere example of *how* possible it would be to do this.

It is important to note that some characters are replaced with others so that they do not interfere with the HTML. For example, the content of

`foo " / \ <`

is replaced with

`foo \" / \ \u003C`

I would **highly** recommend that you consider thinking of an alternative that would satisfy your client, as such a method of parsing another page in order to update another feels very unnecessary.

Assuming you're using PHP, if you *really* need to go through with this, then I would recommend using [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) or `file_get_contents()` to download the document on your server.

I should note that you **must** consider the efficiency of your ideas, as you **certainly** don't want to be downloading the latest document from Google Docs *every* time someone wishes to view one of your pages. I would recommend invoking a re-download upon the request/instruction of a site administrator. Also note that the Google Docs update the server-side version regularly (whilst you're modifying the document). This is important to note, as this would make it possible for your server to download an unfinished document, should you not take this into consideration.

Finally, As an alternative to using Google Docs, I wish to suggest creating an administration control panel for your client to use. Ask him what it is about Google Docs that makes him wish to use it in such a way, and then implement the features that would make your *own* editor an acceptable **alternative** for Google Docs.

Let me know if you need further clarification, or if you desire some example code.

Comment: My workgroup uses Google Docs for writing the documentation and discussing it in real-time, so far I've made the final documentations separately by copypasta'ing the important parts, but this was surely an enjoying read. Deserved more upvotes imo.